# Website for tracking all of the domain names I own

Tags: domain-name

I've been using a spreadsheet to keep track of domain names. Is there a web service anywhere that maintains a domain name database and tracks all the domains we own? The most important feature is that it would have to remind me when it's time to renew, but it would also keep track of all the registrars in my life.

Comment: Shopping questions are off topic but why not use something like Google Spreadsheet? There are plenty of examples on how to script it to send emails when certain criteria are met.

Comment: I just have the registrars email me when my domains are about to expire. They're more than happy to do so.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to serverfault.  Please look at the FAQ to see what questions you can post located [here](https://serverfault.com/faq#questions).  However, there is one called [Domainer](http://www.ragesw.com/products/domainer.html) which will let you know when your domain is about to expire.